# Match sub-string is the twig

Tags: twig, drupal-views, drupal-8

I am developing a new drupal8 website and I can't work out what I am doing wrong! All I need to do is find if a sub-string exists in the variable called output.

```
{% if ((output|raw matches '\b<div class="image"><\\div>\b') == true) %}
     <h1>this is a test</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simplify the `if` expression removing the `true` comparison (is impliciti in the [matches](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#comparisons) statement). So try simply this:

```
{% if output matches '\b<div class="image"></div>\b' %}
     <h1>this is a test</h1>
{% endif %}
```

[Here](http://twigfiddle.com/t5uh46/3) a working example.

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks, It stops the errors but never accesses the if statement

Comment: @purencool can you share the output content? you could use the same twigfiddle strategy

Comment: I have updated http://twigfiddle.com/t5uh46/2 output that is what gets added to the browser

Comment: @purencool ok updated  [here](http://twigfiddle.com/t5uh46/3) with the working version. The problem was about a slash in the closing div tag.

Comment: @purencool answer updated with the last improvement. Let me know if this is working for you also